# Adding an addon to Zotero using bash?

Tags: bash, plugins, add-on, xpi

While trying to install and configure Zotero using a bash script, I'm encountering some difficulties in adding an `.xpi` addon using bash. [The documentation](https://www.zotero.org/support/plugins) says:

> To install a plugin in Zotero, download its .xpi file to your
> computer. Then, in Zotero, click “Tools → Add-Ons”, then drag the .xpi
> for the plugin onto the Add-Ons window that opens.

My closest approach was simulating the "open with" option and chosing "Zotero". However, even when using "open with" manually, Zotero assumes the incoming file is a literature file instead of an addon file. So the implementation:

```
#!/bin/bash
zotero some.xpi
```

Analogous to option 1 of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244836/open-file-from-terminal-in-specific-application), launches Zotero, yet it does not (prompt the user to) install the add-on.

I did not yet find an API or method to load the add-on automatically. Hence I would like to ask: How can I add an arbitrary `.xpi` add-on for Zotero from a bash script?

Answer (score 1):

[The instructions in the documentation](https://www.zotero.org/support/dev/client_coding/plugin_development#setting_up_a_plugin_development_environment) did not work for me, so I found out another method:

One can

1. Download the Zotero standalone version
2. Get the add-on source code
3. Compile the add-on into a build directory that contains an `install.rdf` file
4. Copy this build directory into the `/modules/` directory of the Zotero Standalone Build repository
5. Compile the Zotero Standalone Build repository into a build (exported to `/staging/<your system architecture>/`)
6. Add the instructions to include the new addon when Zotero loads, into the `/staging/<your system architecture>/defaults/prefs.js` file.
7. Start zotero using: `./zotero`.

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/zotero/zotero-standalone-build
...
npm run build

git clone git@github.com<your zotero extension>.git
# Switch out build file to add additional plugin
cp -r "src/build.sh" "src/submodules/zotero/zotero-standalone-build/build.sh"
..
npm build
...
staging/Zotero_linux-x86_64/zotero -purgecaches
```

I created a modified `build.sh` file for the `zotero-standalone-build` which adds the extensions to the `prefs.js` file with:

```
echo 'pref("extensions.something.unopkgPaths", "{}");'  >> "$APPDIR/defaults/preferences/prefs.js"
        echo 'pref("extensions.something.version", "");'  >> "$APPDIR/defaults/preferences/prefs.js"
        echo 'pref("extensions.something.installed", false);'  >> "$APPDIR/defaults/preferences/prefs.js"
        echo 'pref("extensions.something.skipInstallation", false);'  >> "$APPDIR/defaults/preferences/prefs.js"
```

The build command specifics depend on the addon you want to include.